# JavaScript: How can I make this console.log() work?

Tags: javascript

The third log doesn't go through, does anyone know why??
I've been trying to figure out for a while, and I've been struggling a lot.

```
var KnowsUsername = true;
var KnowsEmail = true;
var KnowsPassword = true;
setTimeout(function(){
    var Username = prompt('What is your username?');
    if(Username == '') {
        KnowsUsername = true;
        console.log("Correct username!");
    } else {
        KnowsUsername = false;
        console.error('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', 'Aww! wrong username! try again!');
    }
    if (KnowsUsername == false) {
        return;
    } else {
        if (KnowsUsername == true) {
            var Email = prompt('What is your E-mail?');
            if(Email == '') {
                KnowsEmail = true;
                console.log("Correct E-mail!");
            } else {
                KnowsEmail = false;
                console.error('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', 'Wrong E-mail! try again!');
            }
        }
        if (KnowsEmail == false) {
            return;
        } else {
            if (KnowsEmail == true) {
                var Password = prompt('What is your password?');
                if (!Password == '') {
                    KnowsPassword = false;
                    console.error('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', 'Aww! wrong password! try again!');
                }
            } else {
                if(Password == '') {
                    KnowsPassword = true;
                }
                console.log("Correct password!");
            }
        }
    }
}, 2100);
```

The last console.log doesn't work. I've tried changing it a bunch of times, and none of them worked.

Comment: `!Password == ''` → `Password != ''`. Also, you're making this much complicated than it should have...

Comment: the last `console.log()` is unreachable because of the previous `if (KnowsEmail == false) { return; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if-else` statement for `KnowsEmail == true` is incorrect.

I've fixed incorrect statements and also removed unnecessary satements.

```js
var KnowsUsername = true;
var KnowsEmail = true;
var KnowsPassword = true;
setTimeout(function () {
  var Username = prompt('What is your username?');
  if (Username == '') {
    KnowsUsername = true;
    console.log('Correct username!');

    var Email = prompt('What is your E-mail?');
    if (Email == '') {
      KnowsEmail = true;
      console.log('Correct E-mail!');

      var Password = prompt('What is your password?');
      if (Password == '') {
        KnowsPassword = true;
        console.log('Correct password!');
      } else {
        KnowsPassword = false;
        console.error('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', 'Aww! wrong password! try again!');
      }
    } else {
      KnowsEmail = false;
      console.error('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', 'Wrong E-mail! try again!');
    }
  } else {
    KnowsUsername = false;
    console.error('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', 'Aww! wrong username! try again!');
  }
}, 2100);
```